# Grab IP address from Google via JSON export

Tags: jquery, json, callback, ip-address

You can use certain web services that export a user's IP address in JSON format -- valuable when paired as a javascript callback-- but the services I've found seem to be unreliable.

The two services I've tried are,
http://jsonip.com/ and
http://jsonip.appspot.com,
but they 503 error (service unavailable) often.

```
// Callback to grab JSON
//
function getip(json)
{
    usersIP = json.ip;
}

// External file that returns user IP address
//
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="http://jsonip.com/?callback=getip"></script>');
```

I noticed, however, that Google returns your IP address when you [query "what is my ip"](http://www.google.ca/search?q=what%20is%20my%20ip). I also noticed, that you can [return Google results via JSON](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=what%20is%20my%20ip), however it doesn't include the IP address information.

Any recommendations on pulling in IP address information?

I've used my own PHP scripts, but I'd rather retrieve them from a more reliable source.

And yes, I'm aware there are paid services out there, but work constraints are work constraints.

Comment: What could be more reliable than your own server ?

Comment: Do you actually need the user's ip? or are you looking for the ip to get their location.

Comment: It's to test that the user who is viewing the website is not from known locations -- aka our office, and certain other buildings